How to make my local server's IP address dynamic for a packaged web-view app?
The project is designed for local use, with the server built using JS and the client in HTML and JS. I want to package the client into a web-view app to make it easier to use. However, I'm currently hardcoding the server IP in the client’s JS. If I change the server machine, the IP will change as well, and I won’t be able to update it in the app once it's packaged. What can i do to dont need to change the ip even if i change the server machine?
I thought about asking for the IP when the app opens, but that would be harder, so I'm trying to figure out a way to make it automatic.

If the html file is hosted on that same server you could use relative urls instead of hard coding an ip.

What you can use is a domain name and point it to the IP of the server that is being used at the time. There are free services out there where you can get a sub-domain (eg. my-web-view-app.zapto.org from noip.com) and then point that to your server IP using an "A" record. Then in your client you use the domain as the server IP. You can also buy a domain and use that instead.
If your IP ever changes, you just update the server IP in the domain.
